# rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(544) [sender=3.0.6]

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to delete huge data(~ in TiBs) using rsync command. 
The command is running in background process with nohup. But still it is failing without successfully completing the process with the below mentioned error in log file.

```
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(544) [sender=3.0.6]
```

Please suggest what should be done in this case.
This is the command that I am executing.

```
nohup rsync -a --delete empty_dir/ dir_to_be_deleted/ &
```

Comment: "_I am trying to delete huge data(~ in TiBs) using rsync command_" - wouldn't it make more sense to use `rm`? Faster, more efficient, and certainly more obvious to use the standard tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rsync doesn't work with nohup but using screen we can successfully run rsync in background.
Below is the command

1) Open a screen

```
 screen -S rsync
```

2) Run the rsync process

```
rsync -rvz --delete syncing_to_empty_dir/ folder_marked_for_deletion/
```

3) detach the screen

```
ctrl+A+d
```

This solved my problem and hopes will work for others too.

Comment: RuchikaSharma, can you qualify why you say that, "_rsync doesn't work with nohup_", please?

Comment: @ChrisDavies,
There are a few reasons why rsync might not work with nohup. One reason is that rsync may be reading from stdin, and when you close the terminal, rsync will receive an EOF or EIO error. Another reason is that rsync may be a daemon process, and daemon processes are not typically detached from their input terminal.

Comment: Thank you. However, the example isn't reading from _stdin_, and unless someone specifically uses `--files-from=-` it's never going to happen by accident

Comment: In my case this data was on AWS EFS and so the fastest way to delete or I should say make the directory empty is to sync with an empty directory. @ChrisDavies